# Phonegap - Kendo mobile ui overriding my css

Tags: css, cordova, kendo-ui, overriding

Practially, i have a css file with some classes ,id's and html selectors (index.css) and the kendo.mobile.all.min.css.

I've tried putting it before and after to no avail.

My classes won't work , for example:

```
<div data-role="view" data-title="main-menu" id="main-menu" data-persist="true" class="body" data-transition="overlay:up" >


<h1>Text text</h1>

                            <h2>Another</h2>
<div>
```

This code, when used only with my css and the kendo.common.min.css and kendo.default.min.css files, shows the proper styling with background, when used , in any combination with kendo.mobile.all.min.css all i see is the plain html.

I'm a begginer (still in university) , is there something implicit about this that escapes me? I also tried jquery mobile but quit that because it overrided all my css and got blank html.

Also anyone know how can i change the default android skin from android-dark to android-light without forcing the app to run on one platform? (as in still adapt to different platforms)?

My include order:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>



        <script src="js/load.unload.js"></script>

        <script src="js/hangman.js"></script>





                <link href="css/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />








<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- audio css-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 









    <script src="js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/kendo.mobile.listview.js"></script>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" /> 






<!-- audio js sources-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried the !important thing , didn't work, though the css file is pretty large.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding the !important property to your css to see if that works.

like this:

```
 .button {
   background: red            !important;
   color: white               !important;
   padding: 3px               !important;
   border-radius: 5px         !important;
   border: 1px solid black    !important;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried the !important thing , didn't work, also my custom css file is pretty large.

Comment: if you're running in a browser before going to phone try doing a hard reload (ctrl+shift+r). also check the console for any errors that may have come when the other file is loaded